# Problema al intentar usar animation-timeline en un componente Angular

Tags: css, angular

Quiero usar el `animation-timeline` para mostrar una línea de progreso horizontal cuando se hace `Scroll` en un componente llamado **header** y que utilizo en el **home** de la aplicación. El problema es que no se anima nada. No estoy seguro si es que en `Angular` no se puede hacer esto con `css` y sólo con `JavaScript` o me fala algo más para que funcione.

He probado en todos los navegadores y actualizados.

El mismo código lo he usado en `developer.mozilla` y ahí si me funciona.

**Componente Header:**

```css
#space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffc3c3;
}

#progress {
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #ff3838;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: progress-scroll auto linear;
  animation-timeline: scroll(root block);
}



@keyframes progress-scroll {
  from { width: 0% }
  to { width: 100% }
}
```

```html
<section id="space">
  <ion-progress-bar id="progress"></ion-progress-bar>
</section>

<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Header</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

**Componente Home:**

```css
section{
  height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 30vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;


}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
section:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<app-header></app-header>


<!-- Contenido -->
<ion-content >
  <section>
    <app-circulo-transition />
  </section>

  <section>
    <app-cuadrado-animacion1 />
  </section>

  <section>
    <app-cuadrado-animacion2 />
  </section>

  <section>
    <app-cuadrado-animacion3 />
  </section>
</ion-content>
```